# Keep Autocomplete value when component re-renders React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a SelectForm class component in which I'm using multiple React Material Autocomplete components with nested TextField components to display separate lists of options. The values of the Autocomplete fields are stored in the local state when an option is selected. The idea is that when the user selects the required options and submits the form, the `isSubmitted` state is set to `true` and the Results component is rendered, showing the results that match the selection. If the user then hits an 'Edit Configuration' button in the Results component, the `isSubmitted` state is set to false, which triggers the SelectForm component to be shown again. At this stage, I want the displayed text in the Autocomplete field to be that which is stored in the state (the option that the user initially selected). However, what actually happens is that the label is displayed again in the field, instead of the selected option, even though the option name is still stored in the local state.

I've tried to use the `inputValue` prop on the Autocomplete field to set the value to the relevant state value. This ensures that the correct value is displayed in the field when the SelectForm component renders again, but the field is no longer editable. I want the user to be able to edit it if needed at that stage.

Here are some snippets of the state and an Autocomplete field. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

**State**

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isSubmitted: false,
            form: {
                cpuParent: '',
            }
        }
    }
```

**handleAutoCompleteChange**

```
handleAutocompleteChange = (name, option) => {
    let value = '';
    if (option) {
        value = [option.name]
    }
    this.setState({
        form: {
            ...this.state.form,
            [name]: value
        }
    });
};
```

**Autocomplete Component**

```
{
    cpuParentList &&
    <Autocomplete
        options={cpuParentList}
        name={"cpuParent"}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
        onChange={
            (event, value, reason) => {
                this.handleAutocompleteChange("cpuParent", value);
            }
        }
        style={{width: '100%'}}
        renderInput={
            (params) =>
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    name={"cpuParent"}
                    label={"Select Brand"}
                    variant="outlined"
                />
            }
        />
}
```

Comment: Please, Could you include a CodeSandbox to replicate and find the solution?

Comment: @AdrianNaranjo Sure, here is the link of the demo. I've displayed the state in a paragraph just to show it's holding the value in there but not the dropdown - https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-react-project-skkxt?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Check the answer, I did it before your comment :D

Comment: Just saw it, cheers dude. I've just finished work for the day so I'll give it a go tomorrow and let you know if it worked :)

Comment: @AdrianNaranjo Your answer worked a treat! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suppose that your options for Autocomplete are an array of objects, so you must to save the value like an object, not like a string.

In these lines:

```js
handleAutocompleteChange = (name, option) => {
    let value = '';
    if (option) {
        value = [option.name]
    }
...
```

You were saving value like string array.

SOLUTION

- You need to save value in `object` instead of string, because you need a reference.
- And finally, you need to provide the value for Autocomplete component.

This is a solution code example:

```js
import React from "react";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
class TestAutoComplete extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isSubmitted: false,
      form: {
        cpuParent: null
      }
    };
  }

  handleAutocompleteChange = (name, option) => {
   this.setState({
      form: {
        ...this.state.form,
        [name]: option
      }
    });
  };
  render() {
    // DEFAULT CPUPARENTLIST
    const cpuParentList = [{ value: "item1", name: "Item 1" }];
    return (
      <div>
        <Autocomplete
          // PROVIDE VALUE
          value={this.state.form.cpuParent}
          options={cpuParentList}
          name={"cpuParent"}
          getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
          onChange={(event, value, reason) => {
            this.handleAutocompleteChange("cpuParent", value);
          }}
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          renderInput={params => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              name={"cpuParent"}
              label={"Select Brand"}
              variant="outlined"
            />
          )}
        />
      <p>Value Selected: {this.state.form.cpuParent ? this.state.form.cpuParent.name : ""}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export { TestAutoComplete };
```